# How to play a number of sounds in sequence with Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio

I have a number of mp3 sounds ([i](http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds-folder/mp3/Close_front_unrounded_vowel.mp3), [y](http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds-folder/mp3/Close_front_rounded_vowel.mp3), [e](http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds-folder/mp3/Close-mid_front_unrounded_vowel.mp3) etc.). I would like to play them in a sequence (i.e. without any pauses between them) based on the word given (for ex., `eye`).
Believe, `call(["afplay", "sound.mp3"])` will not work as I need.

Comment: Which python engine are you using to play the mp3 tracks?

Comment: @ArpitGoyal, I use nothing currently. So, I am OK with any engine, which supports OSX.